# could someone explain minimax tic tac toe algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, youtube, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I'm working on the AI of tic tac toe (user vs computer) and I'm using minimax algorithm to implement best move for computer. I've looked at some vids on youtube, and read over some peoples code. However, there are parts of the code I'm still puzzled by what is doing. Let's take for example the following code from tic tac toe minimax function. There's a main if, else if, else statement and everything else derives from there. My main problem is understanding the embedded for loop, and the 2 ifs following that. I've put some comments on the stuff, I think, is doing. I took the sample code from this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_Je9i3aKNk
minimax function for tic tac toe.

```
//minimax function
function minimax(newGrid, depth, player) {
    const gameState = isGameOver(newGrid);
    //if the game is not over, evalute best move for computer
    if(gameState === false) {
        const values = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                const gridCopy = _.cloneDeep(newGrid);
                //if that spot is taken, skip to next loop
                if(gridCopy[i][j] !== ' ') continue;
                //if spot is player, evaluate
                gridCopy[i][j] = player;
                //need clarification
                const value = minimax(gridCopy, depth+1, (player == PLAYER_TOKEN) ? COMPUTER_TOKEN : PLAYER_TOKEN);
                values.push(value);
            }
        }
        //need clarification for computer turn
        if(player === COMPUTER_TOKEN) {
            const max = _.maxBy(value, (v) => {
                return v.cost;
            });
            if(depth === 0) {
                return max.cell;
            }
            else {
                return max.cost;
            }
        //need clarification for user turn
        else {
            const min = _.minBy(value, (v) => {
                return v.cost;
            });
            if(depth === 0) {
                return v.cell;
            }
            else {
                return v.cost;
            }
        }

    //if game state is null return 0
    else if (gameState === null) {
        return 0;
    }
    //if game state is player return negative
    else if(gameState === PLAYER_TOKEN) {
        return depth - 10;
    }
    //if game state is computer return positive
    else if(gameState === COMPUTER_TOKEN) {
        return 10 - depth;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The key to the Minimax algorithm is a back and forth between the two players, where the player whose "turn it is" desires to pick the move with the maximum score. In turn, the scores for each of the available moves are determined by the opposing player deciding which of its available moves has the minimum score. And the scores for the opposing players moves are again determined by the turn-taking player trying to maximize its score and so on all the way down the move tree to an end state.

A description for the algorithm, assuming X is the "turn taking player," would look something like:

- If the game is over, return the score from X's perspective.
- Otherwise get a list of new game states for every possible move
- Create a scores list
- For each of these states add the minimax result of that state to the scores list
- If it's X's turn, return the maximum score from the scores list
- If it's O's turn, return the minimum score from the scores list

You'll notice that this algorithm is recursive, it flips back and forth between the players until a final score is found.

Let's walk through the algorithm's execution with the full move tree, and show why, algorithmically, the instant winning move will be picked:

[image: minimax tic tac toe algorithm]

- It's X's turn in state 1. X generates the states 2, 3, and 4 and calls minimax on those states.
- State 2 pushes the score of +10 to state 1's score list, because the game is in an end state.
- State 3 and 4 are not in end states, so 3 generates states 5 and 6 and calls minimax on them, while state 4 generates states 7 and 8 and calls minimax on them.
- State 5 pushes a score of -10 onto state 3's score list, while the same happens for state 7 which pushes a score of -10 onto state 4's score list.
- State 6 and 8 generate the only available moves, which are end states, and so both of them add the score of +10 to the move lists of states 3 and 4.
- Because it is O's turn in both state 3 and 4, O will seek to find the
  minimum score, and given the choice between -10 and +10, both states
  3 and 4 will yield -10.
- Finally the score list for states 2, 3, and 4 are populated with +10, -10 and -10 respectively, and state 1 seeking to maximize the score will chose the winning move with score +10, state 2.

For more details and implementation of algorithm in code you can got through the following article:

[Tic Tac Toe: Understanding The Minimax Algorithm](http://neverstopbuilding.com/minimax)

[online version tic tac toe](http://perfecttictactoe.herokuapp.com/)

[Source code on github](https://github.com/jasonrobertfox/tictactoe)

[Reference: http://neverstopbuilding.com/minimax](http://neverstopbuilding.com/minimax)

[Here is the presentation slide by us](https://www.slideshare.net/KiranShahi2/ai-based-tic-tac-toe-game-using-minimax-algorithm)